# Class Library project target framework does not display installed .NET versions

Tags: .net, winforms

I have an existing solution with different types of projects targeting the .NET framework 4.5.2. But in the same solution when I add a Class Library project, with target framework Netstandard 2.0,it is not referred by .Net framework 4.5.2,unable to change target framework 4.5.2

Comment: Pay attention to the name of the project template.  Lots of "class library" templates to choose from and you picked the wrong one.  You need the one named "Class Library (.NET Framework)".  Clicking on "Windows Classic Desktop" is a way to cut down on the choices and reduce the odds for a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the picture below there is two options to create a class library. The `.Net Standard` and `.NET Framework`.

`.NET Standard` will only automatically take `2.0` and .Net Framework will let you choose `.NET framework` version

[image]

Comment: I did not choose class library from templates.It is downloaded from internet and added reference to main project.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating a new Class Library project make sure you're selecting **Class Library (.NET Framework)** and not **Class Library (.NET Standard)**

[A short example](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/102569-dllhowto.png)